# How to pass '--list-config' to Jetty when using maven jetty plugin?

Tags: maven, jetty

We can pass arguments like '--list-config', '--list-classpath', etc. when using Jetty's start.jar as shown at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.8.v20150217/startup-classpath.html and http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html

I was wondering how could I pass them on while using Jetty Maven plugin. I tried < jvmArgs > and run-forked but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`jetty-maven-plugin` is just an [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty) for Maven plugins.

It is unrelated to the jetty-distribution's `start.jar` standalone operation.

For the `jetty-maven-plugin` there is no Server Classpath, just the maven plugin's own Classpath, determined by maven, gleaned from the effective pom (pom hierarchy) of your maven build.  Use maven's `--debug` to see the plugin classpath during the execution of that plugin's phase (note: the classpath can change between different phases)

The configuration is also part of the phase that the `jetty-maven-plugin` executes with.  Again, use the `--debug` from maven to see that configuration.

The configuration you see from `start.jar --list-config` is 100% in the scope of the `start.jar` determination from the configuration information starting at `${jetty.base}/start.ini`, and the selected jetty modules, along with your properties to build up a Jetty instance, a "pre-start" configuration that `start.jar` will execute to build up a Jetty instance.

Its like you are asking how to understand a bicycle (jetty-maven-plugin) by looking at an technical specifications manual for motorcycle (start.jar).  There is only inconsequential overlap between the two: 2 wheels of approximately the same size, with handlebars, and a seat.

*Yes, the differences between jetty-maven-plugin and start.jar configuration and startup are that vast.*

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was wondering if there's an equivalent feature.

Comment: Thanks again. Now it's clearer. I don't mean to hijack the question but is there an alternative way to print out maven plugin's own classpath without --debug.

Comment: That's outside of the scope of the plugin, and something that maven does already.